# Restrict Alfresco upload to specific file extension (ex: users can only upload PDFs)

Tags: alfresco

I want to prevent my Alfresco 5.1 users from uploading anything else than ".pdf" and ".xslx" files.

What is the best way to implement that in Alfresco?
Is there a setting, or do I have to write some Java code?

Filtering must be done on the file extension, regardless of MIME types. The restriction must apply via FTP too.

Comment: Do you need to have the validation client side, server side or both?

Comment: @Lista: Server-side only. The restriction must apply via FTP too, so client-side is not an option.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this through simple Alfresco configuration. I'd suggest writing a `Behaviour` that would implement this logic. It will get triggered no matter how something ends up in Alfresco (Share, FTP, custom application, etc).

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-extension-points-behaviors.html

Answer (score 1):

You can not restrict throught FTP. Some ftp client provide file name filter facility,Using that you can Restrict.In alfresco try to create rule ,on that rule execute script ,that script contain code to delete file which is not allow.